# SELECT query with WHERE equivalent in cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have these codes on my controller that gets the inputted value to the text box by the user:

```
$username = $this->request->data['employee_account']['username'];
$password = $this->request->data['employee_account']['password'];
```

I want this kind of query to be implemented using cakePHP code:

```
"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

how can i do this using find()??

Comment: My model name is employee_account.php and the table name where I will select values is employee_accounts. so what am i going to put in the $this->[SOMETHING]->find(); I am receiving an error "Call to a member function find() on a non-object"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have model with name accounts

```
$login = $this->Account->find('first', array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Account.email' => $username,
                            'Account.password' => $password
                        )
                    ));
    if ($login)
    {//do something}
    else
    {
    }
```

Comment: My model name is employee_account.php and the table name where I will select values is employee_accounts. so what am i going to put in the $this->[SOMETHING]->find(); I am receiving an error "Call to a member function find() on a non-object"

Comment: [SOMETHING] should be model name other wise find method wont execute

Comment: Don't fancy escaping the $username/$password?

Answer (score 2):

StuR almost got it right, he's just gone the wrong way about escaping and binding the parameters..

```
$this->EmployeeAccount->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'accounts.username = ?' => $username,
        'accounts.password = ?' => $password
    )
));
```

Additionally, I can't help but think you are trying to log someone in with this? [CakePHP has a built in authentication component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html), which eliminates the need to write a `find()` like this. Also, because the fact that you're needing help to write a very basic SQL query in Cake, I'd suggest reading the [Retrieving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) page in the manual.

Comment: Thanks, to that built in authentication problem.. But I think I have problems in the naming convention. my table is employee_accounts. model name is employee_account. controller is EmployeeAccountsController. is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First off I'd filter your request data and extract the variables for your SQL query:

```
extract(array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $this->request->data['employee_account']));
```

Then this should do the job:

```
$this->accounts->find('all', array('conditions' => array('accounts.username' => $username, 'accounts.password' => $password)));
```

Comment: My model name is employee_account.php and the table name where I will select values is employee_accounts. so what am i going to put in the $this->[SOMETHING]->find(); I am receiving an error "Call to a member function find() on a non-object"

Comment: Have you setup your databases in the config? Have a look at the Cake docs, in your model you need to declare $name = 'model name': http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1001/Understanding-Models

Comment: yeah, I already setup my database in the config. I think I need to change the database name? my database name is employee_accounts. model name is employee_account. controller name is EmployeeAccountsController. cakephp 2.1 . what is wrong?